# Handling early __iter__ termination

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I have a class that implements `__iter__` and I have the following case:

```
for i in MyClass():
    if i == 'some condition':
        break
    # do other stuff
```

I need to be able to handle when iteration is terminated early. Can this be achieved within the classes implementation?

Comment: @Tomer The class has `__enter__` and `__exit__` defined as well, it can currently be used as a context manager, as an iterator or both. The concern is some "clean up" needs to happen if `__iter__` was initiated but not exhausted.

Comment: Does the cleanup have to happen immediately?  If it can wait, you can stick it inside of `__del__`.

Comment: @0x5453 its thread related, so ideally as soon as possible to prevent lingering threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try catching `GeneratorExit`:

```py
class A:
    def __iter__(self):
        # You need to adapt this to your actual __iter__ implementation:
        i = 0
        try:
            while i < 5:
                yield i
                i += 1
        except GeneratorExit:
            print("GeneratorExit")
```

This will work if you do not store the generator, e.g. in

```py
# If you break in any of these two loops, you'll get GeneratorExit printed:
a = A()
for i in a: ...
for i in A(): ...
```

If you store the generator, you'll get `GeneratorExit` only if the generator is garbage-collected without being exhausted:

```py
a = A()
it = iter(a)
for i in it:
    if i == 2:
        break  # Does not print GeneratorExit.

it = iter(a)  # Prints GeneratorExit.
```

In any case, you probably don't want to clean-up if the generator is still alive, otherwise this would get weird:

```py
it = iter(A())
for i in it:
    if i == 2:
        break

for i in it:  # What happens here if you cleaned-up?
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks. The `__iter__` does in fact use `yield`, so `GeneratorExit` is perfect for ensuring resources are properly handled.